# Http File upload using Apache MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: java, c#, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

Below is the Http post method for file upload in c#. What is the equivalent for this code in java which uses apache library. How to add contentDisposition in java and pass byte array value in it. Providing some **online reference** is much appreciated.

**C# Code**

```
            byte[] date = //file in byte format
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(data));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = "\"files\"",
                FileName = "\"" + filename + "\""
            }; // the extra quotes are key here
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(fileContent);

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _url + uri);
            request.Content = content;
```

**My Java Code**

```
         StringBody name = new StringBody("\"files\"", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
         StringBody file = new StringBody("\"" + filename + "\"", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

         HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addPart("Name", name)
                    .addPart("FileName", file)
                    .addBinaryBody("file", data)
                    .build();

        Postmethod = new HttpPost(_url + uri);
        Postmethod.addHeader(useragent);
        Postmethod.addHeader(Accesstoken);
        Postmethod.setEntity(entity);
        Postmethod.addHeader("content-type", contentType);
        response = httpClient.execute(Postmethod);
```

The response status code is 400 .Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: My question is not "write code for me" maybe I should rephrase it.. My question is What is the equivalent code for adding contentDisposition as request payload data.

Comment: Highlighting my question. Providing a sample or a some **online reference** is much appreciated.

Comment: Updated, I did try before asking question. Sorry my bad